# Can the vanishing gradient problem be solved by multiplying the input of tanh with a coefficient?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, backpropagation, sigmoid-curve

To my understanding, the vanishing gradient problem occurs when training neural networks when the gradient of each activation function is less than 1 such that when corrections are back-propagated through many layers, the product of these gradients becomes very small

I know there are other solutions like a [rectifier](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) activation function, but my question is why we could not simply use a variation of the often used *tanh* function.

If the activation function was of the form $\tanh(n x)$ then the maximum possible gradient is $n$. Thus if $n > 1$ we no longer have a case where the product of gradients *necessarily* goes to 0.

Is there some reason why such an activation function would otherwise fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been thinking about this for a while and just found the answer to my own question:

When we replace ℎ() with ℎ() as an activation function we have changed *nothing* about how the activation function works.

All we have done is rescaled all the weights of the network - which we are free to do arbitrarily.

The only stage where $n$ should come into the calculation is the normalization of gradients in the initialization - but a well-converged network should lose any information of the initialization stage (in the ideal case at least).

Answer (score 0):

The **MAXIMUM** possible gradient would be $n$ if the $tanh(nx) = 0$ (for $x = 0$).

But it doesn't tell you anything about what would be the gradient on average, and this is what it's all about - if you move from that zero just so slightly, then the gradient vanishes much faster than it had with a plain $tanh(x)$, and you end up with much more severe gradient vanishing than before.

Comment: perhaps - but with tanh(x) the product of gradients necessarilly tends to 0, whearas here, though it may on average go to zero, it can take any value (up to $2^n$ where $n$ is the number of hidden layers) - are you aware of any research exploring this?

Answer (score -1):

Very interesting idea, but I'm worried about the other type of problem, overflow. As long as we keep multiplying numbers that are less than 1, we won't ever get a back-prop that's larger than 1. But with >1, and especially deep networks, I can imagine you could quickly overflow.

Comment: but the derivative of rectified units can be larger than one

Comment: max(0,x) has a derivative of 0 or 1.

Comment: ...yep got confused sorry